# How to set margin to these UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I created a view with 3 buttons in Xcode, the codes are as follows:

```
UIImage *firstButtonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"firstButton")];
UIImage *firstButtonImgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"firstButtonHightlighted")];
self.firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[firstButton setBackgroundImage:firstButtonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstButton setBackgroundImage:firstButtonImgHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 60+self.aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+20, firstButtonImg.size.width, firstButtonImg.size.height);
[firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonEvent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:firstButton];

UIImage *secondButtonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"secondButton")];
UIImage *secondButtonImgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"secondButtonHighlighted")];
self.secondButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[secondButton setBackgroundImage:secondButtonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[secondButton setBackgroundImage:secondButtonImgHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 60+aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+firstButton.frame.size.height+20.f, secondButtonImg.size.width, secondButtonImg.size.height);
[secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondButtonEvent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:secondButton];

UIImage *thirdButtonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"thirdButton")];
UIImage *thirdButtonImgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"thirdButtonHighlighted")];
self.thirdButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[thirdButton setBackgroundImage:thirdButtonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[thirdButton setBackgroundImage:thirdButtonImgHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.thirdButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 60+aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+firstButton.frame.size.height+secondButton.frame.size.height+20.f, thirdButtonImg.size.width, thirdButtonImg.size.height);
[thirdButton addTarget:self action:@selector(thirdButtonEvent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:thirdButton];
```

but these buttons are closely placed, without the 20 space I added between them, I can't figure out why

Please help me

Comment: Please ask yourself if you really need to be doing UI work in code and not using Interface Builder. Using autolayout will save you hours and hours of work trying to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys

problem solved

it seems that I can't add numbers to rect multiple times

the right codes:

```
UIImage *firstButtonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"firstButton")];
UIImage *firstButtonImgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"firstButtonHightlighted")];
self.firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[firstButton setBackgroundImage:firstButtonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstButton setBackgroundImage:firstButtonImgHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 80+self.aboutViewTop.frame.size.height, firstButtonImg.size.width, firstButtonImg.size.height);
[firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonEvent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:firstButton];

UIImage *secondButtonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"secondButton")];
UIImage *secondButtonImgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"secondButtonHighlighted")];
self.secondButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[secondButton setBackgroundImage:secondButtonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[secondButton setBackgroundImage:secondButtonImgHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100+aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+firstButton.frame.size.height, secondButtonImg.size.width, secondButtonImg.size.height);
[secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondButtonEvent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:secondButton];

UIImage *thirdButtonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"thirdButton")];
UIImage *thirdButtonImgHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"thirdButtonHighlighted")];
self.thirdButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[thirdButton setBackgroundImage:thirdButtonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[thirdButton setBackgroundImage:thirdButtonImgHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.thirdButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 120+aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+firstButton.frame.size.height+secondButton.frame.size.height, thirdButtonImg.size.width, thirdButtonImg.size.height);
[thirdButton addTarget:self action:@selector(thirdButtonEvent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:thirdButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
float yValue =  60+self.aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+20;
self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, yValue, firstButtonImg.size.width, firstButtonImg.size.height);
yValue  = CGRectGetMaxY(self.firstButton.frame)+20; //y+height of first button+20 spacing
self.secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, yValue, secondButtonImg.size.width, secondButtonImg.size.height);
yValue  = CGRectGetMaxY(self.secondButton.frame)+20;
self.thirdButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, yValue, thirdButtonImg.size.width, thirdButtonImg.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 60+self.aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+20, firstButtonImg.size.width, firstButtonImg.size.height);
```

in the first case: 60+20+topViewHeight

```
self.secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 60+aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+firstButton.frame.size.height+20.f, secondButtonImg.size.width, secondButtonImg.size.height);
```

you are getting:
60+20+topViewHeight+**firstButtonHeight**

So  there are no margins.
I think you have to add 20 to second button frame first:

```
self.secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 60+aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+**20.f**+firstButton.frame.size.height+20.f, secondButtonImg.size.width, secondButtonImg.size.height);
```

and 40 to third:

```
self.thirdButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 60+aboutViewTop.frame.size.height+firstButton.frame.size.height+**40.f**+secondButton.frame.size.height+20.f, thirdButtonImg.size.width, thirdButtonImg.size.height);
```